# PrintWriter and FileWriter Instead of using File or Using File ( JAVA ) Program

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

For the simplicity of writing a lot and also boring you guys I just have a question and if you guys can give me another example as well using maybe something simpler.

Here is the code

```
PrinterWriter w = new PrinterWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
```

ok so the above works perfectly fine but so does this

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt");
```

So does this work

```
PrintWriter w = PrintWriter(new File("test.text");
```

Ok so now all of these work but I am more concerned on why does the one in italics work.

I have read some of the documentation and have noticed that it takes a `Writer` as the constructor argument, which `FileWriter` is an extension of.

But if that is true then why does this not work (or maybe it does)

```
FileWriter fw = FileWriter(new PrintWriter("test.txt));
```

I have not yet confirmed if this works but I do not see what this would do anyways ( the others make sense ) but can anyone just explain even the slightest bit of information?

Comment: Why didn't you try it for yourself before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses the Decorator pattern to provide specialized combinations of Writer/Stream

- `Writer` an object you can write characters to
- `PrintWriter` specialized `Writer` that provides formating options, like linebreaks (e.g. `println()`) or `printf`` aso
- `OutputStream` an object to write bytes to

So:

A `FileWriter("test.txt")` is an object you can write characters to, that are written to a file.

A `PrintWriter(new FilteWriter("test.txt"))` is an object that provides formatting options, 
that writes characters to an object that writes to a file.

A `PrintWriter(new File("test.txt"))` is semantically the same, a writer with formatting options that writes characters to a file. (just without an extra step)

`FileWriter fw = FileWriter(new PrintWriter("test.txt));` does not compile.

Two other common Writers are the `BufferedWriter` `StringWriter`. The `BufferedWriter`o ptimizes for larger chunks of writes, it only writes to the underlying `Writer` if the buffer is full or flushed. `StringWriter` is the basic "in memory" implementation that appends to a String.

With that: `BufferedWriter( new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("test.txt")));"` a chunk based writer with no formatting options, that uses a `PrintWriter` and `FileWriter` to write characters to a file.